# Comparing the elements of a vector to entries in a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame `df` with a field `date` that contains dates (of class `Date`).  (They happen to be consecutive dates, like a time series, but they don't have to be for this question.)

I have a vector `v` that contains a bunch of dates, each date corresponding to an "event."

I want to create a new column `df$num_events` in the following way: I want the value of `df$num_events[i]` to be the number of event dates from `v` that are less than or equal to `df$date[i]`.  Thus, `df$num_events` will be a running total of the number of events that have happened on or before each date in `df$date`.

I know that I can use a `for` loop, but is there a cute way to do this elegantly within the tidyverse?  I tried this:

```
df %>% mutate(num_events = sum(v <= date))
```

but the sum wants to aggregate along all of `df$date`, so this doesn't work.  I feel like there may be a way to pull it off with `do`, but I still don't quite get how to use `do`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the [`rowwise`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html) function:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(num_events = sum(v <= date))
```